# Redux state is undefined in a mapStateToProps of build-version of application

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've made a quite simple application, which gets cookie from a server, which contains an encrypted quote in a value, and then it sends cookie back to the server and get JSON with decrypted quote. It was made in a case of a training.

The server is written in Go, and runs on localhost:8080.

To prevent my application from CORS I've defined proxy in `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080/",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    ...
  }
}
```

I've skipped some lines here.

The client side, which is ReactJS app is packed up using `create-react-app` CLI-utility.

Here is the only one and main container of the application:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import * as actions from '../actions';

class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log('PROPS:',this.props);
    this.props.getCookie();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Here is your cookie quote:</h1>
        <p>{this.props.cookieQuote}</p>
        <button onClick={this.props.getCookie}>Update</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log('STATE',state);
  return {
    cookieQuote:state.cookie.quote
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(App);
```

The index.js, which configures the high level of the view options is looking like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import reducers from './reducers';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import App from './containers/App';

const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(reduxThunk));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App/>
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

Here are the reducers:

```
import {GET_COOKIE, SET_COOKIE} from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {quote: 'You deserve a cookie'};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_COOKIE:
      return {...state, quote: action.payload};
    case SET_COOKIE:
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Here how it's combined:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
import cookie_reducer from "./cookie_reducer";

export default combineReducers({
  cookie:cookie_reducer
});
```

And here are the actions:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {GET_COOKIE} from "./types";

const GET_COOKIE_PATH = '/get_cookie';
const SET_COOKIE_PATH = '/set_cookie';

export const getCookie = () => async dispatch => {
  await setCookie();
  const res = await axios.get(GET_COOKIE_PATH);
  console.log(res);
  dispatch({type: GET_COOKIE, payload: res.data.text});
};

export const setCookie = () => {
  axios.get(SET_COOKIE_PATH);
};
```

This is all for code.

So, what is the problem. When I'm starting my application using `npm start`, everything works fine. We are getting data from server and it is viewed perfectly on the screen.

But when I'm trying to run a build version, the state is not delivered to mapStateToProps() in App.js. According to log it is undefined.

Here are the steps of how I make a build version:

```
npm run build
serve -s build
```

---

#### UPDATE

Well, I have realized, that I do not get cookies to the browser on a build version. That was a such problem before a solved it with proxy for server, because I've had a CORS.

Comment: No error message ?

Comment: Nothing at all. I'm just not receiving any state in mapStateToProps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as far I understand when you do `build` in CRA you create static assets which you later host. That means there is nothing (like webpack-dev-server in `dev` mode) to proxy your requests.

Comment: But console of the browser shows, that I'm getting data from server, and I don't get any state, even default, which is:const initialState = {quote: 'You deserve a cookie'};

Comment: what is the message of  `console.log(res);` ?

Comment: well, it's a quite big response there. I have placed it here https://pastebin.com/KubBUGQs

Comment: It seems that I do not get any cookies from server anymore after running the build-version

Comment: I also see data as `undefined` in response you pasted.

Comment: That's right. Well, maybe I need to serve files from build/ directory right from Go server. But I really don't know how to do that...

Comment: In your response you can see that url is: "/get_cookie". So it is hitting the `serve` server (which you start with command `serve -s build`), not `Go` server. Serving it from Go should definetely help. http://www.alexedwards.net/blog/serving-static-sites-with-go

Comment: Yes! That's right! That's what I really needed to do!

Comment: @SanchelliosProg nice!

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the API is called then try to debug from there. You can add a logger to help you find the answer.

```js
const logger = (store) => (next) => (action) => {
    if(typeof action !== "function"){
        console.log('dispatching:', action);
    }
    return next(action);
}
const store = createStore(reducer, compose(
    applyMiddleware(logger, thunk)
    ,window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
));
```

Comment: Yes, API is called. I can see it in a browser console

Comment: What if you add full path ?

Comment: Well, I have realized, that I do not get cookies to the browser on a build version. That was a such problem before a solved it with proxy for server, because I've had a CORS.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Tomasz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4443323/tomasz) who have given a [great example](http://www.alexedwards.net/blog/serving-static-sites-with-go) of serving static sites with Go.

So, everything I needed to do, is to serve the build with go, not with serve-server!

So, in Go code it should look like this:

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/set_cookie", setCookie)
    http.HandleFunc("/get_cookie", getCookie)
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("../client/build"))
    http.Handle("/", fs)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

fs - is a FileServer which serves the static files generated from ReactJS code!